# avoid Process Terminated after .command is run

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I have a .command script, let's say echo 'Hello World'

after double clicking it, it opens up the terminal, spit out the string and then process terminated.

How can I make the terminal alive, instead of being terminated?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/261203/255644).

The answer suggests to put the command `bash` at the end of your script. That way, you will still have an active shell after your program ends.

Comment: It is not actually what I expected. When I run the .command, the terminal opens as a logged in user. when command is done, it says exit; then logout. then the bash comes on, but I no longer has me as logged in user, which is not good.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. When I use the method referenced in my answer on my local machine, it works as expected. A new bash shell opens and `whoami` confirms that I am still logged in as myself. Do you call the `.command` file on you local Mac, by double-clicking in Finder, logged in as yourself, or are there any special circumstances?